# Conda: using installed R in an environment

Tags: conda, environment

I have R installed on my linux and here is the path: `/home/uiuu/miniconda3/bin/R`. I created a new python2.7 environment called py27 and has the path `/home/uiuu/miniconda3/envs/py27/`

When using `conda activate py27`, however, I was unable to call R inside. Do I need to reinstall R in the py27 env? Or I should do something like, to add `/home/uiuu/miniconda3/bin/R` to the py27 env.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to have R and Python co-installed in an environment for most situations. Can you give an example of why you need both on PATH directly? You might get a recommendation for better practice that way.

Comment: The issue is that I cannot use R when I activated the py27 environment, a bit weird to me

Comment: Environments are intended to be isolated. When activating when environment, the other environments are taken off PATH. Technically, you could use `conda activate --stack py27` to keep the previous environment on PATH. But usually one just switches between environments when changing tasks or uses `conda run` to run subprocesses in particular environments.